# Where to sync redux store and firebase?

Tags: firebase, redux, synchronization

I recently started learning react and redux and am confused as how to sync the data? I'm using `create-react-app` and `redux-thunk`.

Suppose I'm making a todolist. So should I add a task into redux and update the entire store to firebase using store.subscribe in index.js?

Or should I update the firebase store and *then* update the redux store? I think this would be the better method as the application would move only in response to the firebase store. **But** this approach slows the application re-render as the data change has to wait for the async request to finish which isn't good on a slow internet connection. And would make the user experience slow.
Like **this**.

```
export const startAddTaskAction = (task) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    database.ref('tasks').push(task)
        .then(() => {
            dispatch(addTaskAction(task));
        });
  };
};
```

Or do I update both simultaneously in the redux store and in firebase in the dispatch? But then what if the users internet connection fails? Firebase won't be able to write to itself but redux would show the task as saved?
Like **this**:

```
export const startAddTaskAction = (task) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    database.ref('tasks').push(task);
    dispatch(addTaskAction(task));
  };
};
```

Which way should I do this and why is it better then the others?

Answer (score 0):

Go with First one you should wait until you push the data into firebase that is the best practice to do.

Let me explain the cases why you should do in this way

1. What if there is no connection at all user able to add all tasks but at the end when he reload the page he will be surprised that there is no data at all.
2. For all crud we use _id which is generated by databases if you don't hit the server you don't even get data at all.
3. Rather than giving unpredictable results to users it's better to let him wait put some time interval to api if it exceeds show some message net connection is slow